# how to enable the user to select two radios and execute a function with their values as parameters

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to enable the user to select one pokemon radio button and one character radio button and execute myfunction with radio button values as parameters

Also while loading the html page a default radio button value is selected, could anyone please tell me how to disable that

I'm using radio buttons and I absolutely do not want to try this with dropdown list

```js
function myfunction() {}
```

```css
ButtonState {
  display: none;
}

.Button {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 4px;
  background: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px #999;
  color: black;
  margin: 4px 2px 4px 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 32px 16px 32px;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s
}

.ButtonState:checked+.Button {
  background: green;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Ash" value="-1" />
    <label class="Button" for="Ash">Ash</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" id="Misty" value="-2" />
    <label class="Button" for="Misty">Misty</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" id="Brock" value="-3" />
    <label class="Button" for="Brock">Brock</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" id="Oak" value="-4" />
    <label class="Button" for="Oak">Oak</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" id="Jessie" value="-5" />
    <label class="Button" for="Jessie">Jessie</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" id="James" value="-6" />
    <label class="Button" for="James">James</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" id="Giovanni" value="-7" />
    <label class="Button" for="Giovanni">Giovanni</label>
  </div>

  <br> <br>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Pickachu" value="1" />
    <label class="Button" for="Pickachu">Pickachu</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Bulbasaur" value="2" />
    <label class="Button" for="Bulbasaur">Bulbasaur</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Charmander" value="3" />
    <label class="Button" for="Charmander">Charmander</label><input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Squirtle" value="4" />
    <label class="Button" for="Squirtle">Squirtle</label><input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Butterfree" value="5" />
    <label class="Button" for="Butterfree">Butterfree</label><input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Pidgeotto" value="6" />
    <label class="Button" for="Pidgeotto">Pidgeotto</label><input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Arbok" value="7" />
    <label class="Button" for="Arbok">Arbok</label><input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Sandshrew" value="8" />
    <label class="Button" for="Sandshrew">Sandshrew</label><input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Jigglypuff" value="9" />
    <label class="Button" for="Jigglypuff">Jigglypuff</label><input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Vulpix" value="10" />
    <label class="Button" for="Vulpix">Vulpix</label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="myfunction()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the button to type="button" - you do not want to submit the form
2. grab the selected buttons - but give the sets different names
3. You can only have ONE checked per set unless you use checkboxes
4. remove "checked" if you do not want a default selected

```js
function myfunction() {
  var checkedName = document.querySelector('input[name="poke-name"]:checked'),
    checkedType = document.querySelector('input[name="poke-type"]:checked'),
    name = checkedName ? checkedName.value : "Nothing selected",
    type = checkedType ? checkedType.value : "Nothing selected"
  console.log("name", name, "Type", type);
}

// to remove default checked:
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var checkedNames = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="poke-name"]:checked'),
      checkedTypes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="poke-type"]:checked');
  for (var i=0,n=checkedNames.length; i<n;i++) {
    checkedNames[i].checked=false;
  }
  for (var i=0,n=checkedTypes.length; i<n;i++) {
    checkedTypes[i].checked=false;
  }
});
```

```css
ButtonState {
  display: none;
}

.Button {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 4px;
  background: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px #999;
  color: black;
  margin: 4px 2px 4px 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 32px 16px 32px;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s
}

.ButtonState:checked+.Button {
  background: green;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="poke-name" class="ButtonState" id="Ash" value="-1" />
    <label class="Button" for="Ash">Ash</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poke-name" class="ButtonState" id="Misty" value="-2" />
    <label class="Button" for="Misty">Misty</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poke-name" class="ButtonState" id="Brock" value="-3" />
    <label class="Button" for="Brock">Brock</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poke-name" class="ButtonState" checked id="Oak" value="-4" />
    <label class="Button" for="Oak">Oak</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poke-name" class="ButtonState" id="Jessie" value="-5" />
    <label class="Button" for="Jessie">Jessie</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poke-name" class="ButtonState" id="James" value="-6" />
    <label class="Button" for="James">James</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poke-name" class="ButtonState" id="Giovanni" value="-7" />
    <label class="Button" for="Giovanni">Giovanni</label>
  </div>

  <br> <br>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="poke-type" class="ButtonState" id="Pickachu" value="1" />
    <label class="Button" for="Pickachu">Pickachu</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poke-type" class="ButtonState" checked id="Bulbasaur" value="2" />
    <label class="Button" for="Bulbasaur">Bulbasaur</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poke-type" class="ButtonState" id="Charmander" value="3" />
    <label class="Button" for="Charmander">Charmander</label><input type="radio" name="poke-type" class="ButtonState" id="Squirtle" value="4" />
    <label class="Button" for="Squirtle">Squirtle</label><input type="radio" name="poke-type" class="ButtonState" id="Butterfree" value="5" />
    <label class="Button" for="Butterfree">Butterfree</label><input type="radio" name="poke-type" class="ButtonState" id="Pidgeotto" value="6" />
    <label class="Button" for="Pidgeotto">Pidgeotto</label><input type="radio" name="poke-type" class="ButtonState" id="Arbok" value="7" />
    <label class="Button" for="Arbok">Arbok</label><input type="radio" name="poke-type" class="ButtonState" id="Sandshrew" value="8" />
    <label class="Button" for="Sandshrew">Sandshrew</label><input type="radio" name="poke-type" class="ButtonState" id="Jigglypuff" value="9" />
    <label class="Button" for="Jigglypuff">Jigglypuff</label><input type="radio" name="poke-type" class="ButtonState" id="Vulpix" value="10" />
    <label class="Button" for="Vulpix">Vulpix</label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="myfunction()" />
</form>
```

Comment: WOW!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! within few mins you solved it sir!!! i thought it is complex coding, i have been working on this since morning and got fed up and posted it and went to eat.. REALLY SHOCKED TO WAKE MY COMPUTERSCREEN WHICH HAS ANSWER IN IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! you just made my day thanks a lot sir im really really really greatfull may god bless you and your knowledge more sir